# Using DirectShow API from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, directshow, directshow.net

We would like to leverage the codec capabilities of DirectShow from Silverlight. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

MediaStreamSource is really the closest you will get to accessing decoders in Silverlight.

You also may want to look at this project:  http://directshow4sl.codeplex.com/ It is a managed re-imagined version of DirectShow.

Answer (score 0):

In short (because I can't even think of a long answer) no, you can't use DirectShow in Silverlight.

Comment: Is there any possibility to access decoder functions of supported formats in Silverlight?