# Media Players used in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, media-player

I want to use a media player in C# that reads these extensions : wmv,api,flv,mp3,mp4 and swf..

I tried Silverlight media player but its working with wmv and mp3 only.. and the same with the mediaElement in silverlight.. And FlowPLayer will only play flv, mp4 and mp3.

Has anyone any suggestion ?
  Thanks alot !!

Comment: Not sure if this helps (seems it may have been abandoned), but you could try http://directshow4sl.codeplex.com/.  This is also a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185302/using-directshow-api-from-silverlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since LongTail (aka JWplayer) can play flv files  i converted all my files to flv and played them with LongTail

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use VLC media Player ActiveX ,here is a Project that helps you to integrate http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Agreed, I have used the ActiveX control for VLC before and I encountered no issues at all.